# Infix to postfix function error: control may reach end of non-void function

Tags: c, compiler-errors, stack, postfix-notation, infix-notation

/*
This is a code that changes infix notation to postfix notation.
I used FILE/IO to get infix notations and the infix.txt file looks like

```
 3   
 2+4*2-1;  
 9+3^2^(3-1)*2;   
 2*((7-2)/3+4)^2%3;
```

My question is I get error saying **"control may reach end of non-void function" on the last two functions, icp and isp.** How can I fix this?
*/

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdlib.h>



#define MAX_SIZE 100
#define ENTER 0x000d

void infixtopostfix(char expression[]);
char get_token(char expression[], int *index);
void push(int *top, char token);
int pop(int *top);
int icp(char op);
int isp(char op);
char stack[MAX_SIZE];



int main(void) {
    int i, num;
    FILE *file;
    char expression[MAX_SIZE];
    if((file=fopen("infix.txt","r")) == NULL) {
        printf("No file.\n");
    }
    fgets(expression, MAX_SIZE, file);
    num = atoi(expression);
    for(i=0; i < num; i++) {
        fgets(expression, MAX_SIZE, file);
        printf("%s", expression);
        infixtopostfix(expression);
    }
    fclose(file);
}



void infixtopostfix(char expression[]) {
    char token;
    char element;
    int top=0;
    int index=0;

    for(token=get_token(expression, &index); token!=';'; token=get_token(expression, &index)) {
        if(isdigit(token)) printf("%c", token);
        else if(token == ')') {
            while (stack[top] != '(') {
                element = pop(&top);
                printf("%c", element);
            }
            pop(&top);
        }
        else {
            while (isp(stack[top])>=icp(token)) {
                element = pop(&top);
                printf("%c", element);
            }
            push(&top, token);
        }
    }
    while((token=pop(&top))!=0) printf("%c", token);
    printf("\n");
}



char get_token(char expression[], int *index) {
    char token=expression[(*index)++];
    return token;
}



void push(int *top, char data) {
    if(*top < (MAX_SIZE-1)) stack[++(*top)] = data;
}



int pop(int *top) {
    if(*top > -1) return stack[(*top)--];
    else return 0;
}



int icp(char op) {
    switch (op){
        case '(' : return 20; break;
        case '+' : return 12; break;
        case '-' : return 12; break;
        case '*' : return 13; break;
        case '%' : return 13; break;
        case ';' : return 0;
    }
}



int isp(char op) {
    switch (op){
        case '(' : return 0; break;
        case '+' : return 12; break;
        case '-' : return 12; break;
        case '*' : return 13; break;
        case '%' : return 13; break;
        case ';' : return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: What if `op` is *none* of the things you check for in the `switch` statements? What do you return then? A function must *always* return a value if it has been declared to return something.

Comment: Oh and by the way: If you make any kind of parser for user-entered data, then you *must* be able to handle illegal or erroneous or otherwise weird input.

Answer (score 2):

While you may believe that your methods will only ever get one of these 6 characters, the compiler has to assume that any character can be passed in.  At the moment, these methods will not return anything if you pass in, for example, `'x'`.

You need to specify a `default` action for all characters not otherwise covered by your switch.  Whether this is returning a default value or throwing an exception, that is up to you.  But it's nonetheless a possibility your code needs to handle.

Answer (score 0):

like this:

```
}//end switch
fprintf(stderr, "\nunrecognized OP(%c) is specified.\n", op);// '/', '^'...
return -1;//or exit(-1);
```